# Creating models in 3ds max and exporting as .x for XNA

Tags: xna-4.0, 3dsmax

I have created a few models in 3DS max which contains textures, geometry and animations . .however .fbx doesnt really support textures.. So im planning to use .x format.. I have seen a few converters in pandasoft but once i unzip the file and place the .dle file in the plugins folder of 3D max gives an error saying failed to initialize.. 
Is there any way to convert my .max models into .x format ? ? I dont know blender so that isnt an option. . I'm currently using 3ds max 2013

After adding the .3DS object content importer. . i get the following error:

[image]

[.3Ds files along with the solution](https://www.dropbox.com/sh/zpbehsommsrwr4h/-cqb2TDGsp)

Comment: FBX surely does support textures, maybe you are doing something wrong. And for X exporting I recommend kW X-port instead of Panda.

Comment: i installed it . . and wat to do after that?

Comment: It installed and everything went okay but i dont see the Kw-xport option when in the file format when i try exporting

Comment: I think you can only have one exporter per file format, try deleting Panda first.

Comment: I did already but i still dont see xW port exporter anywhere

Answer (score 2):

I recommend just using the native 3DS file format. There is an open source [project](https://github.com/tgjones/osiris) that contains a content processor allowing you to do just that. To add the file type as an option follow Microsoft's tutorial on adding a [custom processor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb447743.aspx).

Comment: but xna only accepts .fbx and .x formats right?

Comment: XNA accepts anything there is a content processor for. XNA ships with an .x and .fbx content processors. That library adds an .3ds content processor.

Comment: so i should download the source and place it where?

Comment: Added a link to the microsoft tutorial on adding custom processors.

Comment: I know this might be a little bit annoying but i really need help with it..i have already added the 2 .dll files in that project into my reference but wat about the other src file? . . if i try to run the demos then it gives errors like.. osiris.dll missing or smth

Comment: Click the references drop down and if there are little yellow triangles remove those references and re add them.

Comment: There is a reference to osiris.dll i'm guessing but its nowhere to be found in the files..only nexus.dll and meta smth dll.. also there is no osiris.content.pipeline.dll

Comment: Open Osiris.csproj and build it to get osiris.dll. Open Osiris.Content.Pipeline.csproj and build it to get Osiris.Content.Pipeline.dll.Or you can add the projects to your solution and reference them by project.

Comment: Omg . . thank you i got all the .dlls needed and their demos are also working.. but one last question . . the models they are using in their demos are .fbx and not .3ds ..so all i needed to do is just use the Content.Load<Model>("Myspace") and myspace can be a .3ds file ?

Comment: Yes that is correct.

Comment: Okay . . i did that and i added all the .dlls (osiris,osiris.content.pipleline,nexus,meshellator) and then added my model using content.load now XNA says cannot autodetect which importer to use for neby.3ds . . Specify the importer than handles this file in your project

Comment: The same drop down you use when you selected .x or .fbx should now have a .3ds option. Click the file and look at the properties view.

Comment: So i selected the properties and set the content importer to be Autodesk - FBX and content processor to be Model-XNA? it does display the .3DS models now but the texture is lost somehow

Comment: MAke sure you have built the content project at least once. There should be a content importer that says 3ds.

Comment: After adding all the dlls.. i have built my project already ..i dont see .3ds content importer but xna gives a  Warning2 The referenced assembly "Osiris.Content.Pipeline" could not be resolved because it has a dependency on "Microsoft.Build.Framework, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" which is not in the currently targeted framework ".NETFramework,Version=v4.0,Profile=Client". Please remove references to assemblies not in the targeted framework or consider retargeting your project. SimpleCamerasTutorial

Comment: Okay my bad.. i added the osiris.content.pipeline.dll not in my contentpipeline but in the main project . .so now i can select .3ds obj - osiris framework

Comment: But now there is a huge error..once i did select the content importer to .3DS object . . i'll add it above the img

Comment: Please upload the .3ds and I'll see if I can reproduce the error.

Comment: I dont think the error is because of my model.. i will upload both the model and the error so you can see..cos it happens regardless of what .3ds model i'm using

Comment: I have added the solution and the .3Ds files